# SQL max(DateTime) and category filter without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written the below query :

```
SELECT DateTime, configId, rowId
FROM linkedTableDefinition a,
INNER JOIN tableDefinition b,
ON a.Target = b.Id
INNER JOIN ViewWithInfo c,
ON a.Target = c.Id
```

This gives the following output:

```
DateTime           configId    rowId
12-09-2013 11:00     4           12
12-09-2013 12:00     4           12
12-09-2013 13:00     3           11
12-09-2013 12:00     3           11
12-09-2013 11:00     4           11
```

What I need of this output is the following: per rowId and configId combination I need the highest value from the datetime column. So from above example I want the following output:

```
DateTime           configId    rowId
12-09-2013 12:00     4           12
12-09-2013 13:00     3           11
12-09-2013 11:00     4           11
```

Does anyone know the answer? I would like to avoid GROUP BY because the select statement will be extended with a lot more columns.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
The current query:

```
SELECT testResults.ResultDate, testResults.ConfigurationId, TestResultsTestCaseId
FROM dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory workItemLink
INNER JOIN dbo.DimWorkItem workItem 
ON workItem.System_Id = workItemLink.TargetWorkItemID
INNER JOIN dbo.TestResultView testResults
ON testResults.TestCaseId = workItemLink.TargetWorkItemID
WHERE 
RemovedDate = convert(datetime, '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
AND workItemLink.SourceWorkItemID = 7
AND workItem.System_WorkItemType = 'Test Case'
```

Comment: @JustinHui The only thing I've written is the essential part of the query, because else it will be very specific. The linkedTableDefinition contains the links of the parentId. The parentId is passed through a remote procedure. The table definition contains information of the item itself and is for filtering purposes. The view contains the data in the select statement. All these tables are from a software product that has already been purchaesed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DateTime, configId, rowId, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY configId, rowId ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM linkedTableDefinition a
    INNER JOIN tableDefinition b ON a.Target = b.Id
    INNER JOIN ViewWithInfo c ON a.Target = c.Id
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: You have to give me more details. What rows are/aren't filtered ?

Comment: Thanks in advance it is almost working. The only thing that isn't working correctly is filtering on the configId's. The combination configId and rowId must be unique and from this unique combination the highest date.

Comment: @mrtentje: Then you have to replace `PARTITION BY rowId` with `PARTITION BY configId, rowId`.

Comment: @mrtentje: for DATETIME literals I would use '9999-01-01T00:00:00.000'  (there is a "T" separator between date part and time part).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, substituting proper joining fields as appropriate:

```
SELECT testResults.ResultDate, testResults.ConfigurationId, testResults.TestCaseId,
    (SELECT MAX(ResultDate) FROM dbo.TestResultView WHERE TestCaseId = testResults.TestCaseId AND ConfigurationId = testResults.ConfigurationId) AS MaxDate
FROM dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory workItemLink
INNER JOIN dbo.DimWorkItem workItem 
ON workItem.System_Id = workItemLink.TargetWorkItemID AND    workItemLink.TeamProjectCollectionSK = workItem.TeamProjectCollectionSK
INNER JOIN dbo.TestResultView testResults
ON testResults.TestCaseId = workItemLink.TargetWorkItemID
WHERE 
RemovedDate = convert(datetime, '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
AND workItemLink.SourceWorkItemID = 7
AND workItem.System_WorkItemType = 'Test Case'
AND workItem.System_RevisedDate = convert(datetime, '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the results that are not appropriate are not filtered (I updated my question with my current query, hope that will make more sense)

Comment: I have updated my suggested query based on your recent edit. If I understand correctly, you are looking to include the most recent ResultDate from TestResultView for each TestCaseId while still having a row for each ResultDate/ConfigurationId/TestCaseId combination.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know much about the columns in your table but it would be something like this....
Query in CROSS APPLY with get the highest TOP 1 date for every result and then feed into the result set or outer query..

```
 SELECT configId, rowId, tbl.DateTime
    FROM linkedTableDefinition a,
    INNER JOIN tableDefinition b,
    ON a.Target = b.Id
    INNER JOIN ViewWithInfo c,
    ON a.Target = c.Id
                       CROSS APPLY
                                  (
                                   SELECT TOP 1 DateTime
                                   FROM whatevertable
                                   WHERE whatevertable.CommonCol = TabeFrmOuterQuery.CommonCol
                                  ORDER BY DateTime DESC
                                    ) tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the results that are not appropriate are not filtered (I updated my question with my current query, hope that will make more sense)

Comment: FROM dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory workItemLink
INNER JOIN dbo.DimWorkItem workItem 
ON workItem.System_Id = workItemLink.TargetWorkItemID AND    workItemLink.TeamProjectCollectionSK = workItem.TeamProjectCollectionSK
Why you are Joining tables on these multiple columns ???

Comment: This SQL query will be used in a stored procedure. The parent will be passed and all the children will be fetched. This information is stored in the FactWorkItemLinkHistory. The type of the child is stored in the DimWorkItem. To ensure each child is part of a collection there is a join on multiple columns